# RESTlet ClientResource with progress bar

Tags: android, file-upload, restlet, android-progressbar, clientresource

I'm creating an android app which is uploading files to RESTlet server. I'm using below code.

```
Representation file = new FileRepresentation(filePath, MediaType.IMAGE_ALL);
FormDataSet form = new FormDataSet();
form.setMultipart(true);
form.getEntries().add(new FormData("file", file));
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(url);
cr.post(form);
```

The question is: How can I monitor uploading process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an asynk task to do it.

See here a simple example:

```
private class UploadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        // Your upload code with rest client
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

You can see a more consistent and complete example [here](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-asynctask-example-download-progress/)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I have to pass progress parameter to publishProgress() method but how can I get this variable from ClientResource object?

Comment: you cant. Rest is one direction comunication. You only see the result in the final. You can use a progress dialog without percent.